# Como llenar una tupla, iterando desde la salida de una consulta sql

Tags: sql, foreach, tuplas

```
        public List<Tuple<int, int>> GetTupleDetailedLog()
{

    var query = (from c in _context.Lk_business_rules
                 join v in _context.Business_rules_detailed_log on c.User_story_number equals v.User_story_number
                 where c.Status_id_fk == 3
                 group new { c, v } by new { c.Rule_description, c.User_story_number} into cv
                 select new
                 {
                     number = cv.Select(cv => cv.v.User_story_number), //this should be the first int on tuple
                     count = cv.Select(cv => cv.v.Row_id.Count()), //this should be the second int on tuple
                 });

    var TupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
    {
        Tuple.Create(number?, count? ),
    };

    TupleList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(number?, count? ));
    return TupleList;
}
```

Hola gente! tengo un problema, mi salida de la consulta me va a devolver dos enteros... basicamente es la primera vez que me toca trabajar pasando de una estructura a otra y no se muy bien por donde encarar, calculo que deberia resolver con un foreach, pero es que no se ni como tomar la salida de la consulta... esta me devuelve 2 enteros... necesito meterlos en la lista de tuplas, nada mas...

Comment: ¿que lenguaje es amigo?

Comment: C# y linq o sql

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo si `query` devuelve solamente una fila de `{number, count}` o muchas filas.

Si devuelve solo una fila, cambia el codigo de Tuple como asi:

```
var TupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
TupleList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(query.number, query.count));
return TupleList;
```

Pero si hay muchas filas:

```
var TupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

foreach(var item in query){
    TupleList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(item.number, item.count));
}

return TupleList;
```